# How to find saved file in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have saved a file. I have not given a path to this. In the project folder, nowhere can I find the file.

Is there any method that will tell me where the default path is where the file has gone?

```
model_file = "test.h5"
model.save(model_file, overwrite=True)
```

Comment: Well, what is `PATH`? You're joining the filename with that.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I only added that later.

Comment: `print(os.path.abspath(os.curdir))`

Comment: @JustinEzequiel thank you very much for the help!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(os.getcwd())` will print the working directory, where relative paths start from (and where a relative filename such as `foo.txt` will end up in).

Comment: Thank you very much! :)